# Adobe Air htmlloader not showing wmv video

Tags: video, air, adobe

In an Air application, I'm using the HtmlLoader to display web pages.
Flash Video inside the pages displays fine, but a page with a wmv or asf file will only display a blank area where the embeded Microsoft Media player would normally be.

I thought it might be that htmlloader cannot load a plugin, like the Microsoft Media player, but it does manage to load the Acrobat Reader plugin when rendering a PDF, so I figure in theory it should work.

I've search high and low but cannot find any reference that points to either it's possible or not.

Has anyone managed to have .Wmv play in a Webpage within the HtmlLoader control in Adobe Air.

Thanks
Greg